# Open Python IDLE and Run Command

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

I am working with an engineering software that allows me to run python scripts internally. However, it doesn't provide me with an IDLE which I need.

I know I can store my required variables using Pickle and then load them latter. So basically I can write a script to load all variables, lets call this **VarLoader.py** . I also now that I can use the below to open a python idle:

```
import idlelib.PyShell
idlelib.PyShell.main()
```

**But** I don't know how to make it automatically run VarLoader.py in the opened IDLE. I mean something like the below would be ideal:

```
import idlelib.PyShell
idlelib.PyShell.main(VarLoader.py)
```

I also tried the below which didn't work:

```
import sys
sys.argv=['-c','VarLoader.py']
```

Any help and thoughts is appreciated.

P.S. I also know that I can do the below but I want something more professional:

```
import os
os.system(' '.join(['python','idle.py','-c','execfile('VarLoader.py')']))
```

Comment: Idle is a development environment and does not add anything but overhead for production execution of already developed programs.  So it is unclear to me why you want to execute VarLoader.py with Idle from within the engineering software.

Comment: In standard Python as installed, `import idle.PyShell` does not work; 'import idlelib.PyShell` does.  Also, importing PyShell is not, or at least no longer, the 'approved' way to start Idle.  What version of Python are you using and how was it installed?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy you are right about idlelib, just a typo in here.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I use Python 2.7.8 and its working fine!
The reason for needing idle is that I am still in the developing process and use IDLE as a debugging tool.
By the way do you have any suggestions, I mean I am just an amateur programmer so knowing the suggestions of a pro is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of trial and error I found the solution. In case anybody in future has same problem, it can be solved as below:

```
import sys
sys.argv=['','-n','-t','My New Shell','-c','execfile("VarLoader.py")']
import idlelib.PyShell
idlelib.PyShell.main()
```

Comment: You can create a Windows shortcut that runs `"C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" -n -t "My New Shell" -r "Path\To\VarLoader.py"`. Change `"C:\Python27"` to the directory where you installed Python. I'm not sure why you need `-n`; that option is deprecated in IDLE 3.